# TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

The following code is my View"

```
   <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-repeat="obj in myData.arr | myfilter">
         {{obj}}
        </div>
   </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript Code. I had created a custom filter using angular.

```
 app.controller('myController', function($scope){

       $scope.myData ={arr: [{name:'Rohith',age:23},{name:'Arun',age:24},{name:'Venki',age:25}]};

  });

  app.filter('myfilter',function(){
      return function(input, minage){
              var filtered = [];
              if(!minage){
                         minage = 24;
               }
               for(var i=0;i<=input.length;i++){
                        var value = input[i];
                        if(value.age >= minage){
                                 filtered.push(value);
                        }
               }
               return filtered;
       }
  });
```

When I tried to run, console shows:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined

What's wrong in my code? Please explain

Comment: Basics of debugging: Try `console.log(value)` before reading the `value.age`, see what does it output.

Comment: Some notions of defensive programming may help, you should not use a property of value without checking if value is not 'nothing'. Another option would be to use a for each loop, this ensures that you get a valid item and thatz you are not out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the array index

```
for(var i=0;i<=input.length;i++){
}
```

`i` should be less than `input.length` NOT less than or equal to

So, it should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
}
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/MqNA4KKayqjV8gDNbPGB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` variable  is equal to `{name:'Rohith',age:23}` which is *single object* and not an *array*.You should not access  like this

```
var value = input[i];
```

It should be

`var value = input`